# C++: template specialization, std map choosing wrong specialization

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, traits

I have a template that calls other templates based on their stl type. Using map`<int, int>` works fine, however, if I call the specialization with a map`<int, std::string>` it chooses the generic specialization, and not the map specialization. How can I ensure that any kind of maps ( `<int, int>` , `<int, string>` and so on) pick the right specialization?

It basically looks like this, class A uses two traits to specialize

```
template<typename T, typename P=trait<T>>
class A{
public
    typedef P traits
  //

    A(T a, T b){}

    static T foo(T a, T b){
        T d = traits::foo(a,b)
    }
};
```

traits:

```
template<typename T>
struct trait{
    static T foo(T a, T b){
        //do something
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct trait<std::map<T,T> >{
    static std::map<T,T> foo(std::map<T,T> a, std::map<T,T> b){
        //do something
    }
};
```

in main:

```
std::map<int, std::string> a = {{1,"a"},{2,"b"}}
std::map<int, std::string> b = {{3,"c"},{4,"d"}}
A some_name(a,b);
some_name.foo(a,b);
```

Comment: can you please provide a [mcve]? Those are just the templates, but I guess you instantiate them somewhere

Comment: Use two template parameters instead of one, i.e. `template <class Key, class Value>`?

Comment: I don't get this closure. The question is clear enough that Quentin came up with the solution in a mere two minutes (albeit in the comments, which I disagree, but oh well) . Sure, the code provided is, although minimal and verifiable, not complete, but an MCVE is not really a requirement, but more of a recommendation.

Comment: Thanks a lot Quentin and Cássio Renan, this worked wonderfully. Have a nice day :)

Comment: @CássioRenan The bar for a question should be quite a bit higher than "it is *literally possible* for somebody to intuit an answer to it." MCVE is a really good bar - "my code doesn't work, here is example code demonstrating my problem" is substantially better than "my code doesn't work, here is a fragment that if you figure out how to fill in the dots yourself, might eventually demonstrate a problem which may or may not be my actual one"

Comment: @Barry This was not an intuition on some problem that may or may not be what the OP was looking for. It was clear, from his question, what his problem was, and what he needed to do to solve it. This is why I disagree with the closure. After all, isn't it the whole point of moderation that we have answerable questions? This was answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different template parameters for the key and value of the map:

```
template<typename K, V>
struct trait<std::map<K,V> >{
    static std::map<K,V> foo(std::map<K,V> a, std::map<K,V> b){
        //do something
    }
};
```

But the problem with that is that it will fail for maps with custom comparison classes, or with custom allocators:

```
A<std::map<int, int>>  // specialization for std::map
A<std::map<int, float>> // specialization for std::map
A<std::map<int, float, std::greater<int>>> // generic. Oops.
```

So, your best bet is actually using a variadic template for the specialization:

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct trait<std::map<Ts...> >{
    static std::map<Ts...> foo(std::map<Ts...> a, std::map<Ts...> b){
        //do something
    }
};
```